# Windows XP laptop doesn't appear in WSUS All computers list

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, wsus

I have this one laptop that doesn't appear in WSUS all computers list.  We have about 23-25 PCs/laptops/servers in the network, all, but one are listed in WSUS.

This is what I have done so far:

**1) Changing Updates on local PC:**

- Go to your Windows XP client and start a new Microsoft Management
  Console (MMC). At Start, Run, type MMC.
- Use Ctrl+M to add a new snap-in.
- Click Add, and then add the Group Policy Object Editor for the Local
  Computer.
- Click Close, and then click OK.
- Expand the Local Computer Policy.
- Under Computer Configuration, go to Administrative Templates, Windows
  Components, Windows Update.
- In the right-hand pane, double-click Specify intranet Microsoft
  update service location.
- Configure the settings to reflect my WSUS server.
- Click OK and then close the MMC without saving it.

executed **wuauclt.exe /detectnow**

**2) Edited registry key to be pushed to the PCs using GPO**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"WUServer"=http://wsusserver
"TargetGroupEnabled"=dword:00000001
"TargetGroup"="WINXP"
"WUStatusServer"=http://wsuswerver
```

**3)** executed **wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow**

**4)Synchronised and refreshed the group**

I am running out of ideas here.  The client is running Windows XP pro, WSUS version is 3.0 and is running on Windows 2008 R2 64-bit.

Please, help!

Thanks!

**EDIT 13.IX.2012 @ 15.40 CT**

I should have also mentioned that we do have a Windows Update GPO for workstations group and that laptop is a part of that group.

**EDIT 13.IX.2012 @ 18.03 CT**

Here are the [image: results].  Now, after googling the error that's the solution I came across and it didn't help:

-> Stop the Automatic Updates service and BITS service.

```
net stop wuauserv

net stop bits
```

-> Delete “%windir%\softwaredistribution” directory.

-> Start the Automatic Updates service and BITS service. When these two services have been started, they will auto-create “softwaredistribution” and its subfolder at system directory.

```
net start wuauserv

net start bits
```

-> After the “%windir%\softwaredistribution” directory has been generated, please let the client contact the WSUS server immediately.

```
wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow
```

-> After 15 minutes, please check the client to confirm whether it detects needed updates.

**Edit 14.IX.2012 @ 9.59 CT**

1) Okay, I ran **nslookup** on the WSUS server:

```
Server:  xxxx.xxxxxxx.local
Address:  x.x.x.2

Name:    xxx-xxx.xxxxxxx.local
Address:  x.x.x.36
```

2) I **pinged** the WSUS server (name):

```
Pinging xxx-xxx.xxxxxx.local [x.x.x.36] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for x.x.x.36:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

3) I **pinged** the WSUS server (IP):

```
Pinging x.x.x.36 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from x.x.x.36: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 10.3.1.36:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

I don't believe it's a DNS issue, but I might be mistaken.  Anything you need to run to check DNS issue?

Comment: 1. Why would you be manually configuring Windows Update on a computer joined to the domain when you should be using GPO to configure Windows Update? 2. Have you confirmed that your Windows Update GPO is being applied to the computer in question?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, I am sorry, I should have mentioned it in my post.  GPO is applied to workstation and that laptop is a part of that group.

Comment: George, joeqwerty meant to ask: do you assign the update server and group within the GPO?  Regardless, post results of [the diag tool](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/7/6/976d1084-d2fd-45a1-8c27-a467c768d8ef/WSUS%20Client%20Diagnostic%20Tool.EXE) (refer to [the readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/b/e4bc4153-be1f-460f-800e-69c6a1857d68/readme.htm) ).

Comment: OK, the computer should show up in the All Computers group as well as the target group. If it's not showing up in the All Computers group, then I would suspect that the GPO isn't being applied. Have you run gpresults or RSOP for the computer in question to verify that the GPO is being applied? Also, you know that that is a WSUS group not an AD group, right?

Comment: @joeqwerty I know the difference.  & that's the issue, it should... but it does...

Comment: @mbrownnyc I posted the results.  I googled that error & followed the instructions I listed to no luck...

Comment: Can the XP client resolve the WSUS server name as configured in your GPO?

Comment: joeqwerty points out, looks like you've got a DNS problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty Just added an edit.  I don't think it's a DNS issue.

Comment: @mbrownnyc Thanks for your help, but like I said I don't think it's a DNS issue.

Comment: @George, It's not clear to me from your edit where you ran the nslookup and ping test from. Did you run them from the XP computer?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, from the XP computer in question.

Comment: OK. Can you open/access the WSUS URL from the XP computer?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes.

Comment: "The 0x80072EE7 error code may occur if the client computer cannot find the correct IP address when it tries to resolve a URL for the Windows Update Web site or for the Microsoft Update Web site. This error may occur if the Hosts file contains a static IP address." [(source)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883821).  Use [the network troubleshooter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308007) and post results. Or use netdiag.exe from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546).  Or just use [this fixit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883821#FixItForMeAlways0x80072EE7).

Comment: @mbrownnyc it's a 50 page result report from netdiag.exe, I am not going to post it here, it'll be time consuming for anyone to look through. Anything in particular you want me to post here, out of that report?

Comment: You tell me.  You see the word "error" or "warning" in that report?  Anything interesting to you (as a professional IT person)?  What about a problem with the HOSTS file?

Comment: You seem to be using a proxy. Maybe anything to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you can ping a server, but you can't communicate with WSUS on the WSUS port.

Been a while since I used WSUS 2.0, and I can't remember if I was using port 80 or some other port, but I always specified the port that I was using:

```
"WUStatusServer"=http://wsusserver:8530
```

-- and you need to check the spelling of your server name in the GPO: that's an easy mistake to make.

You need to check what port the server is using, and that nothing else has grabbed that port, and that the firewall at both server and client allows connection on that port.